# Manually installed files to display in dash

Tags: 11.10, installation, unity-dash

I download an application from a website in its .tar.bz2 form as opposed to through apt-get or through the software center as I usually do (I don't think it matters but just in case, the application in question is Sublime Text 2).

To install it I just extracted the folder to /usr/share with sudo privileges however I can't seem to be able to add it to the dash, I know I can pin it to the launcher but I would like to know how to properly install files myself as this is clearly the incorrect way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for adding manually installed program to the dash and launcher you have to write a desktop files for it (which end with `.desktop` ) .

the desktop file have this form in usual :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=application name
Exec=the command which you have to launch your application 
Comment= a small description for this application 
Icon= the directory for the icon which you want
```

this file is a very simple one , there is a lot of options that you can add to it .

then you have to put it into this directory :

`/usr/share/applications/`

if you want to add an icon for this program add your icon to this directory :

`/usr/share/pixmaps`

and then configure the `.desktop` file to user this icon .(in the `Icon` field )

it will appear in the dash now , or you may have to logout and login again.