# Which paths are valid in a .desktop file?

Tags: launcher, .desktop

I have followed the instructions in many answers like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93775/manually-installed-files-to-display-in-dash) to create a proper launcher for everyone's very favorite user friendly IDE installed from tar (otherwise I would get a very old version from USC). A few hours later I still can't make it run.

I installed eclipse on `~/opt/eclipse/`, (in order to run it today I open a terminal and type `opt/eclipse/eclipse`) so I filled out the Exec field as `Exec=$HOME/opt/eclipse/eclipse`. This might be error 1, what should I put there instead?

In the Icon field, I wrote the path to the eclipse icon in the same folder: `$HOME/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm`. What should I replace this with? [the .eclipse anatomy](https://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/) was my reference for using the `$HOME` variable.
From memory, the following steps were taken:

1. `cd /usr/share/applications/`
2. `sudo touch eclipse.desktop`
3. `sudoedit eclipse.desktop` (heads up: only sudoedit can write on that file)

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Eclipse
   Type=Application
   Exec=$HOME/opt/eclipse/eclipse
   Comment=Launches eclipse IDE
   Icon=$HOME/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
   ```
4. `ls -l eclipse.desktop`

   `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   139 Jul  5 21:41 eclipse.desktop`

And now when I type eclipse on the Dash, all I get is a shortcut to eclipse's icon.xpm. Is there an error in my .desktop file, provided eclipse is in `~opt/eclipse/eclipse`? Is it necessary to copy the eclipse icon to `/usr/share/pixmaps`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, as one first commenter pointed, I can't use `$HOME` (or any environment variable) in a `.desktop` file. I have to use the literal path or a more elaborate command. And having copied the icon to `/usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.xpm`, just writing `Icon=eclipse` is enough to create an icon. Therefore, my eclipse.desktop looks like this:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Name=Eclipse
    Type=Application
    Exec=/home/[my username]/opt/eclipse/eclipse
    Comment=Launches eclipse IDE
    Icon=eclipse
```

And it works!
Thanks to all who helped.